# error path sdk react native linux

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I have installed some needed like: nodejs, python2, android studio, but when running react, error, possibly wrong path, but I check for the path I think is correct, please help

```
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug...
Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes precedence.
java.lang.RuntimeException: SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.getAndCheckSdkFolder(SdkHandler.java:102)
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/rojib/Documents/react/lat3/React-Native-Sample/android/app/build.gradle' line: 104

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 27.013 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

SDK location on android studio : /home/rojib/Android/Sdk, Is there something wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

enter this line to your `package.json` file in `scripts`

```
"android": "ANDROID_HOME='Your android SDK Location' node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js run-android",
```

and after enter this line open terminal and run this

```
npm run android
```

hope it'll work for you...